# How can i use kentor authentication services in my web application for authencation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, kentor-authservices

Single sign on is very new concept to me. can anyone help me  to implement 
**kentor authentication service**s in my existing web application.
 my application is developed in asp.net mvc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its really very simple to implement kentor auth service in asp.net MVC.

Click following link:
[Steps to implement Kentor auth service for SSO (Single sign on)](https://dagarmohit.blogspot.in/2016/12/single-sign-on-using-kentor-authservice.html)